# node: piping a stream to stdout leaks memory

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

In node v8.9.1 on MacOS 10.12.6:

The minimal script below creates a `Readable` stream that produces an infinite supply of the string "yes." It is then piped to `stdout`. As far as I can tell, it's written according to the guidelines for writing custom `Readable` streams. Particularly, it stops yielding data when `push()` returns `false`.

And yet, when I run it from a terminal, the memory usage of the process will balloon infinitely, reaching 2GB very quickly, and beyond. This seems to indicate some kind of infinite buildup in the `stdout` stream.

Can anyone diagnose this and explain what is happening behind the scenes?

```
var stream = require("stream");

var yesStream = new stream.Readable({
  read: function(length) {
    while (yesStream.push("yes\n")) {}
  }
});
yesStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Likely https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1741